# Unable to know when a specific region on screen is being touched?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx version 0.9.9
Here is my code for detecting whether a specific area of screen is being touched:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2();
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY());
        if (playRect.contains(touchPos)) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }
    }
```

Now playRect is this

```
playRect = new Rectangle();
    playRect.x = 400 - playImage.getWidth() / 2;
    playRect.y = 240 - playImage.getHeight() / 2;
    playRect.width = 128;
    playRect.height = 64;
```

playImage has dimensions 128*64.My problem is touch is not being detected where it should be but is slightly misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, but does some button changes its position?
I think the problem is with your play rectangle.
Please, try to output the rectangle and touch position and tell me what you got.

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2();
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY());
        System.out.println(Gdx.input.getX()+" "+Gdx.input.getY()+" "+playRect.toString());
        if (playRect.contains(touchPos)) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that with getY() you are getting the Y coordinate with the  y=0 being at the top of the screen,while the camera has its y=0 at the bottom ,you need to reverse the y coordinate.

```
touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY());
```

Comment: It's either this or that they're using a camera. The touches may be using a different coordinate system. They might need to call unproject from the camera...